# Prime divisor of the form $2kp+1$ that divides $2^p-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, self-learning

The book that I'm reading (Elementary Number Theory by Underwood Dudley) gives a Theorem:
If $p$ and $q$ are odd primes and $q|a^p-1$, then either $q|a-1$ or $q=2kp+1$, for some integer $k$.

Then it gives a corollary;  Any divisor of $2^p-1$ is of the form $2kp+1$.

Then it gives an exercise; Using the corollary, what is the smallest prime divisor of $2^{19}-1$?

So I go through $k=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...$ and I find nothing....So I check the back of the book and it says that $191$ is the smallest prime divisor ($191=2\cdot5\cdot19+1$) since when $k=1..4$ the numbers are composite.  Yet $191\not|2^{19}-1$ since, after checking, $2^{19}-1$ is itself a prime number; $524287$.

So I ask, what have I done wrong to screw this up?  I can not for the life of me understand where my calculation errs... I've checked a couple of times and $2^{19}-1$ is a Mersenne Prime...

Comment: Maybe there was a glitch in the Matrix...

Comment: that's what i was thinking...anyway to find errata for particular books?

Comment: The book can be found [here](https://archive.org/details/ElementaryNumberTheory). But I didn't see any errata.

Comment: If $2^{19}-1$ is a prime number, than its smallest prime divisor simply is $2^{19}-1$. Probably, the exercise was to show, that $M_{19}$ is prime and the formulation is somewhat misleading.

Comment: Well, perhaps you are right and his answer of 191 in the back of the text was the error.  I think it was just an error on the author's part, but it did help my review of Mersenne primes...

Comment: Try $2^{29}-1$ instead, just for fun. It has three factors.